# Taking Top K Occurrences

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Having millions of numbers in a list, I want to take top `K` occurrences. MMA `Commonest` is very slow so I write my own versions:

```
a=RandomInteger[{1,1000000},50000000];

MyCommonest1[a_,n_]:=Take[SortBy[Tally[a],Last],-n]

MyCommonest2[a_,n_]:=(b=Tally[a];Take[b[[Reverse[Ordering[b[[All,2]]]]]],n])

MyCommonest3[a_,n_]:=(b=Tally[a];b[[Take[Ordering[b[[All,2]]],-n]]])

MyCommonest4[a_,n_]:=Take[SortBy[Tally[a],-#[[2]]&],n]
```

Timings:

```
1.68
1.12
1.15
1.70
```

Can it be any faster?

**Edit**

The C# counterpart of this problem in SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402947/fastest-way-for-grouping-and-selecting-list-of-integers-top-occurrences).

Comment: Related Q/A: [Extracting Pareto elements...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15257/125)

Answer (score 11):

The only improvement I can think of:

```
comm[a_, n_] := #[[ Ordering[#[[All, 2]], -n] ]] & @ Tally[a]
```

Or if you don't want the counts:

```
comm2[a_, n_] := #[[ Ordering[#2, -n] ]] & @@ (Tally[a]\[Transpose])
```

Test:

```
MyCommonest2[a, 15] // Timing // First
comm[a, 15]         // Timing // First
comm2[a, 15]        // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.3276
>
> 0.3056
>
> 0.2932
> ```

Comment: Try sorting the list, *then* tally... might be surprised, ~40% boost in some short tests.

Comment: @rasher `Sort` is much slower than `Tally` on the OP's input list, at least in v7.  What data are you using?

Comment: e.g., `RandomInteger[2000000,2000000]`. On the loungebook, might be a cache locality effect, but it's consistent, and even larger with unpacked target since sort packs it... interesting.

Comment: Fiddled with the above some more: Same on WS, but in both cases, only when duplication is low does this happen, otherwise sort slows things dramatically. Probably useless effect, but interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

Another one, seems roughly on par with Mr Wizard's `comm2` on my machine.

```
comm3[a_, n_] := Pick[#1, UnitStep[#2 - RankedMax[#2, n]], 1]& @@ Transpose[Tally @ a]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
jsat = #1[[Join @@ SparseArray[
  Threshold[#2,{"LargestValues",15}]]["NonzeroPositions"]]]& @@ (Tally[#]\[Transpose])&;
```

This returns more than `k` elements because of the ties.

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = RandomInteger[{1, 1000000}, 50000000];
jsat[a, 15] // Timing // First
comm[a, 15] // Timing // First
comm2[a, 15] // Timing // First
comm3[a, 15] // Timing // First
MyCommonest2[a, 15] // Timing // First

0.64062
0.75000
0.75000
0.71875
0.78125
```

Comment: Darn, beaten by a function I don't have. ;-p  At least my computer is faster than yours. ^_^

Comment: @Mr.W still on version 7? Re my machine, yet another reminder to install more memory;)

Comment: Yes, until v10 ships.  `a` takes only 200MB; I doubt it's a memory issue.