# Classifying poker hands by pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

I am working on this question posed in a *Mathematica* course revised in 1998. Here are the instructions:

> **Poker Hands**
>
> You are to define and show working examples of a function "`poker[]`". 
>   The function "`poker[]`" should take five integers, each between 1 and
>   13, and output the best poker hand.  (True poker experts should note
>   that we are ignoring suits for simplicity.)
>
> The possibilities from best to worst are: "Five of a kind", "Four of a
>   kind", "Full house" (three cards of one kind and two of another),
>   "Straight" (five consecutive, distinct cards), "Three of a kind", "Two
>   pair", "Pair", and "High card" (the case in which none of the above
>   apply).
>
> Examples: `poker[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` should return `"full house"`;
>   `poker[1, 1, 3, 4, 4]` should return `"two pair"`.
>
> Hint #1: There are many combinations of two of a kind:  the pair might
>   be in the first two cards, the second two cards, the first and third,
>   and so on.  To deal with this, consider sorting the five arguments
>   before sending them to a second function with particular pattern
>   definitions.
>
> Hint #2:   Use multiple definitions for this second function, along
>   with pattern matching.  Here are sample definitions for two hands.
>
> ```
> poker[a_,a_,a_,a_,a_]:="Five of a kind" 
>
> poker[a_,a_,a_,b__]:="Three of a kind"
> (* the name b is unnessary, although the BlankSequence is not *)
> ```

```
Clear[poker]
poker[0,0,0,0,0];
poker[a_?NumberQ,b_?NumberQ,c_?NumberQ,d_?NumberQ,e_?NumberQ]:=Sort[poker[a,b,c,d,e]]
poker[a_,a_,a_,a_,a_]:="Five of a kind"
poker[b_,a_,a_,a_,a_]:="Four of a kind"
poker[a_,a_,a_,a_,b_]:="Four of a kind"
poker[b_,b_,a_,a_,a_]:="Full House"
poker[a_,a_,a_,b_,b_]:="Full House"  
poker[a_,a_,a_,b_,c_]:="Three of a kind"
poker[b_,c_,a_,a_,a_]:="Three of a kind"
poker[b_,a_,a_,a_,c_]:="Three of a kind"
```

As is evident from the from the error messages and incorrect answers below, I have made a/some mistake(s), even the outputs that correctly identified the "hand" added `Sort[]` to the output. I had at first thought that "hands" were only identified when the four or three similar cards (in the case of Full House) were at the beginning of the sort, however that theory was disproved once the Three of a kind hands were inspected. I have not defined the rest of the "hands" because it became evident that I had made a mistake in the definitions I had already written.

```
poker[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> Sort["Five of a kind"] -- correct *)

poker[3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> Sort["Four of a kind"] -- correct *)

poker[3, 3, 3, 2, 3]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> Sort["Three of a kind"] -- should be "Four of a kind" *)

poker[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> Sort["Full House"] -- correct *)

poker[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> Sort["Three of a kind"] -- should be "Full House" *)

poker[1, 2, 1, 3, 1]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> Sort["Three of a kind"] -- correct *)

poker[2, 1, 2, 3, 2]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> Sort["Three of a kind"] -- correct *)

poker[3, 3, 1, 3, 2]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> Sort["Three of a kind"] -- correct *)

poker[4, 1, 5, 3, 2]
(* (prints) $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
 -> poker[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -- correctly not identified *)
```

Comment: The first definition of `poker` is simply calling itself, which calls itself, etc. You have a rather strange functional syntax. What is the `Sort` function doing her?

Comment: poker[a_,a_,a_,b__]:="Three of a kind" is kinda just wrong. Even if you already weeded out five of a kind (don't people get shot for that?), it will still match a full house or four of a kind.

Comment: Think about sorting the input before plugging it into the function which decides which hand it is.

Comment: [This](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node513.html) and [this](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node516.html) discussions may be relevant.

Comment: Maybe one example of the failure mode in your question might provide sufficient an example ? :)

Comment: I condensed your post by removing all the repeated messages. Next time please consider not including every single message and message about the messages.

Comment: This may interest you: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6494/826

Comment: @Mr. Wizard Thank you, I notice that you used the `~` sign which I have not gotten to yet in the course, so I can’t say that I fully understand the code, but I am hopeful that I will get to the point that I will be able to.

Comment: @Clif I'm somewhat notorious around here for using that notation, though I try to use it less as many people have trouble reading it.  It is "infix" notation for a function with two arguments, i.e. `f[a,b]` can be written `a ~f~ b`.  Besides its use in Code Golf I feel that is has legitimate benefit once you get use to it, though I don't believe I have written an explanation of that position other than in chat long ago.  Note that I specifically add space around `~f~` in my example as I find that greatly helps readability in practical use.  Experiment with it, but be careful of precedence.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jonathan Shock's comment is very pertinent. The specific issue you have is that you are defining a recursive function with no absorbing state. So even if the arguments to the `poker` function are already in sorted order, calling `poker[args]` sends the input to the poker function itself and then sorts the output. There's no end to this, and the `Sort` is in the wrong place, as you can see by the output that does come out, with `Sort` still wrapped around it.

Here is an alternative approach that still teaches you about patterns, but avoids the unnecessary and problematic recursion. I only put in a few of the replacement rules, but you get the idea.

```
Clear[poker]
poker[args__?NumberQ] /; Length[{args}] == 5 := 
 With[{hand = Sort[{args}]},
  hand /. {{a_, a_, a_, a_, a_} -> "Five of a kind", 
     {a_, a_, a_, a_, b_} -> "Four of a kind", 
     {b_, a_, a_, a_, a_} -> "Four of a kind", 
     {a_, a_, a_, b_, b_} -> "Full house", 
     {b_, b_, a_, a_, a_} -> "Full house"}]

poker[wrongnumberofargs__] /; 
  Length[{wrongnumberofargs}] != 
   5 := "Are we playing poker or canasta?"
```

A couple of things to note about this:

- I used  [`Condition` (`/;`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) to ensure that only five-card hands are valid.
- I used  `With` to define a local constant (see [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/8) for some excellent information about the different scoping constructs in Mathematica.
- When applying a list of [replacement rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) using [`ReplaceAll` (`/.`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) , earlier rules are applied before later ones, so put the most specific rules first in the list.

---

Playing with the patterns a bit, they can be condensed down to one rule per hand type, as follows:

```
ClearAll[poker]
SetAttributes[poker, Orderless];
poker[hand__?NumberQ] /; Length[{hand}] == 5 :=
 {hand}/.{
  {a_, a_, a_, a_, a_} -> "Five of a kind",
  {___, a_, a_, a_, a_, ___} -> "Four of a kind",
  {a_ .., b_ ..} -> "Full House",
  {___, a_, a_, a_, ___} -> "Three of a kind",
  {___, a_, a_, ___, b_, b_, ___} -> "Two Pair",
  {___,a_, a_,___} -> "Single Pair",
  a_ /; Max@Differences[a]==1 -> "Straight", 
  _ -> "High"
}

poker[wrongnumberofargs__] /; 
   Length[{wrongnumberofargs}] != 5 := "Are we playing poker or canasta?"
```

Note: this makes use of the `Attribute` `Orderless` which eliminated the need for the explicit `Sort`. Also, it makes liberal use of the fact there are only five cards in the hand and that the rules are applied in order, as mentioned above.

---

`Orderless` appears to have interesting consequences. If you convert the patterns above to functions, e.g.

```
{a_ .., b_ ..} -> "Full House"
```

becomes

```
poker[a_ .., b_ ..] := "Full House"
```

and run `DownValues[poker]` you notice some interesting things. All the instances of `BlankNullSequence` (`___`) appear ***first*** in the pattern. This implies that further simplifications can be made:

```
ClearAll[poker]
poker[wrongnumberofargs__] /; 
  Length[{wrongnumberofargs}] != 5 := "Are we playing poker or canasta?"

SetAttributes[poker, Orderless];
poker[a_, a_, a_, a_, a_] := "Five of a kind"
poker[_, a_, a_, a_, a_] := "Four of a kind"
poker[a_ .., b_ ..] := "Full House"
poker[__, a_, a_, a_] := "Three of a kind"
poker[__, a_, a_, b_, b_] := "Two Pair"
poker[__, a_, a_] := "Single Pair"
poker[hand__] /; Max@Differences[{hand}]==1 := "Straight" 
poker[__] := "High"
```

First, only one definition has a `Condition`. Second, all instances of `BlankNullSequence` within a pattern have been merged into one at the *beginning* of the pattern, and converted to `BlankSequence` (`__`). Third, the `BlankNullSequence` in "Four of a kind" has been changed to `Blank` (`_`). Lastly, the same conversions *cannot* be made to the above code using `ReplaceAll` and have it still work. There the order of the patterns matter because only the patterns that make up `poker` are `Orderless`.

Comment: For didactic purposes, one may also use the `Orderless` attribute rather than explicitly sorting the arguments.

Comment: @Clif did you run `Clear[poker]`, first?

Comment: @rcollyer Yes and it works as expected now.

Comment: @Clif I added a complete version, except for straight ...

Comment: @Clif and now straight has been added, too. Plus, I simplified the pattern for Full House.

Comment: @Clif last one, I swear. I added some observations about `Orderless` and its consequences. They're worth the read.

Comment: @rcollyer, Thank You. I appreciate the time that you have put into your explanations.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps not the intended approach, but you could use `Tally` to count the matching cards and make the pattern matching very simple:

```
poker[x__] := Sort[Tally[{x}][[All, 2]]] /. {
   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} -> If[Sort[{x}] - Min[x] == {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, "straight", "high"],
   {1, 1, 1, 2} -> "pair",
   {1, 2, 2} -> "two pair",
   {1, 1, 3} -> "three",
   {1, 4} -> "four",
   {5} -> "five",
   {2, 3} -> "full house",
   _ -> "cheating!"}
```

Comment: Something similar to the solution I was going to propose ... +1

Comment: I like the answer and will have to look into "Tally" more closely.