# Poker hold'em simulation optimisation

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction

The following funcition evaluates poker hands:

```
f1[a_List] := Reverse /@ Map[Length, #, {2}] &@a;
f2[a_List] := Reverse /@ (Sort /@ SortBy[# /. {"A" -> 14, "J" -> 11, "K" -> 13, "Q" -> 12}, Length] & /@ (Split /@ Sort /@ Transpose[#])) &@a;
f3[a_List] := Flatten@f2[a][[2]] - 1;
f4[a_List] := f1[f2@a];
carddeck = Reverse[Flatten[Map[({{"♡", #}, {"♣", #}, {"♢", #}, {"♠", #}}) &, Join[Table[i, {i, 2, 10}], {"J", "Q", "K", "A"}]], 1]];
cardpicture[{suit_, val_}] := Framed[Column[{val, suit}, Center, 0, ItemSize -> {3/2, 1}, ItemStyle -> Directive[10, "Label", Switch[suit, "♡" | "♢", Darker[Red, 0.2], "♣" | "♠", Black]]]];
cd = Flatten[{Range@13, 
SortBy[carddeck /. {"J" -> 11, "Q" -> 12, "K" -> 13, "A" -> 14}, First] /. {11 -> "J" , 12 -> "Q", 13 -> "K", 14 -> "A"}}, 1];
sc[a_List] := (a[[All, 2]] /. {"A" -> 14, "J" -> 11, "K" -> 13, "Q" -> 12}) - 1;
sortbysc[a_List] := (Transpose@(SortBy[#, First] &@Thread@{sc@a, a}))[[2]];

eph[a_List] := Module[{straight, e, f, g, pp, pl, pr, pq, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, q1, r1, s1, t1, u1, v1, w1, x1, y1, z1, ff, hh, jj, ll, zz},
pl = 371293; pr = 13; pq = pr; g = sortbysc@a;
straight = MemberQ[Sort /@ Take[Partition[Join[Table[i, {i, 2, 10}], {"J", "Q", "K", "A"}], 5, 1, 1], 9], Sort[Last[Transpose[a]]]];
e = f3@a; f = f4@a;
z = (pr^(-#) & /@ Range[5])(*high card*); z1 = Total[z*e];
y = (pr^(-#) & /@ {1, 1, 2, 3, 4})(*pair*); y1 = Total[y*e];
x = (pr^(-#) & /@ {1, 1, 2, 2, 3})(*two pairs*); x1 = Total[x*e];
w = (pr^(-#) & /@ {1, 1, 1, 2, 3})(*three of a kind*); 
w1 = Total[w*e];
v = (pr^(-#) & /@ Range[5])(*straight*); v1 = Total[v*e];
u = (pr^(-#) & /@ Range[5])(*flush*); u1 = Total[u*e];
t = (pr^(-#) & /@ {1, 1, 1, 2, 2})(*full house*); t1 = Total[t*e];
s = (pr^(-#) & /@ {1, 1, 1, 1, 2})(*four of a kind*); 
s1 = Total[s*e];
r = (pr^(-#) & /@ Range[5])(*straight flush*); r1 = Total[r*e];
q = (pr^(-#) & /@ Range[5])(*royal flush*); q1 = Total[q*e];
zz = If[g[[All, 2]] == {2, 3, 4, 5, "A"} && f[[1]] != {5}, {{19*10^6},       "straight", Flatten[{{Last@g}, Most@g}, 1]}, If[g[[All, 2]] == {2, 3, 4, 5, "A"} && f[[1]] == {5}, {{2*19*10^6}, "straight flush", Flatten[{{Last@g}, Most@g}, 1]},
If[straight,If[ f[[1]] == {5},
If[Sort[Last[Transpose[a]]] == {10, "A", "J", "K", "Q"}, {pl {8*pq + q1}, "royal flush", g}, {pl {8*pq + r1}, 
"straight flush", g}], {pl {4*pq + v1}, "straight", g}],
If[ f[[1]] == {5}, {pl {5*pq + u1}, "flush", g},
Switch[f[[2]],
{1, 4}, {pl {7*pq + s1}, "four of a kind", g},
{2, 3}, {pl {6*pq + t1}, "full house", g},
{1, 1, 3}, {pl {3*pq + w1}, "three of a kind", g},
{1, 2, 2}, {pl {2*pq + x1}, "two pairs", g},
{1, 1, 1, 2}, {pl {1*pq + y1}, "pair", g},
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {pl {z1}, "high card", g}
]]]]]];
```

Something like the following then can be used to simulate a hold'em game with `n` players:

```
ff[p_Integer, li_List] := 
If[Length@li < 5, 0, N[Total[Module[{m, aa, b, cc, dd, e, f, g, h, i, t, q},
m = Take[li, 2];
f = Drop[li, 2];
aa = Partition[RandomSample[Complement[carddeck, Flatten[{m, f}, 1]]],          UpTo@2];
b = Flatten[#, 1] & /@ Thread@{ConstantArray[f, p - 1], Take[aa, p - 1]};
cc = Complement[carddeck, Flatten[{Flatten[{b}, 2], Flatten[{m, f}, 1]}, 1]];
dd = RandomSample[cc, 2];
e = Flatten[{f, dd}, 1];
g = Last@Sort[Last@Sort[eph /@ Subsets[#, {5}]] & /@ (Flatten[#, 1] & /@Thread@{ConstantArray[dd, p - 1], b})];
h = Last@Sort[eph /@ Subsets[#, {5}]] &@Flatten[{m, f, dd}, 1];
i = If[g[[1, 1]] > h[[1, 1]], 0, If[g[[1, 1]] < h[[1, 1]], 1, 1/2]]] & /@ Range@100]]];

Clear[list]
list = {};
compex[n_Integer] := Quiet@Module[{},
Column@{Dynamic[If[Length@Setting@# < 5, #, Grid[{{Quiet@
ff[Last@Select[Setting@#, NumericQ], Select[Setting@#, NumericQ@# == False &]]}}, Alignment -> Left]] &@Dynamic[list], SynchronousUpdating -> False],
Grid[Partition[Table[DynamicModule[{pressed = False}, With[{idx = cd[[i]]}, 
Button[If[i < 14, cd[[i]], cardpicture@cd[[i]]], pressed = ! pressed;
list = If[pressed, Append[list, idx], DeleteCases[list, idx]], 
Appearance -> Dynamic@If[pressed, "Pressed", Automatic]]]], {i, 65}], 13], Alignment -> Left]}];
```

eg

```
compex[5]
```

This is a simulation with only `100` games. Can this be sped up to give a more accurate percentage?

NB

```
Rest /@ First /@ SplitBy[SortBy[eph /@ Subsets[carddeck, {5}], First], First]
```

sorts all possible 7462 possible distinct hands, but I don't know (once saved as `.txt` file & then imported):

```
ab = %;
Export["ab.txt", ab];
ab = ToExpression[Import["ab.txt", "List", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]];
```

(since it takes a while to evaluate) whether this can be utilised to speed up the simulation.

(where up to 7 cards are selected; the first 2 being the players own hand, and the rest is the flop, river, etc., and the number pressed in the top row is the number of players in the game), which gives an approximate percentage win.

Comment: That is very dense code with short, non-intuitive names and no comments. It will be very time consuming to pick it apart and figure out where it is slow. Have you timed any of the individual pieces? Also, your hand categorization code could likely be recast to take advantage of the pattern matcher, cf. [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26182/52).

Comment: @rcollyer that code does well in finding the 10 different types of hands, but the above evaluates *all* possible hands.

Comment: Right, and there is no way for me to tell that without extensive digging into the code. It would be worth your time (and the time of the volunteers on this site) for you to adopt better naming, organization, and commenting practices. I _might_ still dig into it tonight as is, but I doubt it.

Comment: @rcollyer ok thanks - meanwhile, I'll try to name & organise more clearly

Comment: holy cow that's a lot of code.  May I suggest you go solve http://projecteuler.net/problem=54 and look at some cleaner solutions in the forum?  It would at least make reviewing code easier if it were shorter.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard haha :) Yes, it is rather botched together - I suspect it can be cleaned up significantly! I'll have a go & update when done.

Comment: Some immediate thoughts: move stuff out of the module that only needs computing once (like z, y, x etc).`Power` is listable so you can do `pr^-{1,2,3}` instead of `pr^(-#)&/@{1,2,3}`. `z.e` is usually faster than `Total[z*e]`. Treat all card values internally as numbers, only convert 11 to "J" and 12 to "Q" for display.

Comment: @SimonWoods thanks for tip - will try to work that in to cleaned up function

Answer (score 5):

I only  post this in case it stimulates much better answers:

```
suits = Style[#, 40] & /@ {"\[HeartSuit]", "\[ClubSuit]", 
    "\[DiamondSuit]", "\[SpadeSuit]"};
tup = Tuples[{suits, Range[13]}];
cards = Row[#, Frame -> True] & /@ tup;
f[a_] := Module[{s, r, u, r1, r2, t},
  {s, r} = Transpose[List @@@ a[[All, 1]]];
  u = Union[s];
  r1 = Sort[r];
  r2 = Sort[r /. {1 -> 14}];
  t = Reverse@Sort[Tally[r][[All, 2]]]; 
  If[Length@u == 
     1 && (Differences[r1] == {1, 1, 1, 1} || 
      Differences[r2] == {1, 1, 1, 1}), "straight flush", 
   If[Length@u == 1, "flush", 
    If[(Differences[r1] == {1, 1, 1, 1} || 
       Differences[r2] == {1, 1, 1, 1}), "straight",
     Which[t == {4, 1}, "four of a kind", t == {3, 2}, "full house", 
      t == {3, 1, 1}, "three of a kind", t == {2, 2, 1}, "two pairs", 
      t == {2, 1, 1, 1}, "pair", t == {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, "nothing"] 
     ]]]]
rd[n_] := Table[RandomSample[cards, 5], n]
```

Example:

```
{Row[#], f@#} & /@ rd[20] // Grid
```

[image]

```
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]
With[{ta = f /@ rd[100000]}, 
 ParetoPlot[ta, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Grid[{#1, #2/100000.} & @@@ SortBy[Tally[ta], -#[[2]] &]]]]]
```

[image]