# How to tell Mathematica a function is invariant under argument permutation

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions

I want Mathematica to simplify my expression using  `MySymmetricFunction[x,y] = MySymmetricFunction[y,x]`,  so that

```
expr = MySymmetricFunction[x,y]-MySymmetricFunction[y,x];
Simplify[expr]
```

yields 0.

I tried

```
MySymmetricFunction[x_, y_] = MySymmetricFunction[y,x]
```

but here Mathematica assumes recursion.

Please note, that I don't want to implement an explicit version of `MySymmetricFunction[x,y]` as of yet.

**edit:**
As a follow up question:
Why does this give zero

```
SetAttributes[MySymmetricFunction, Orderless]
MySymmetricFunction[x,y]-MySymmetricFunction[y,x]
```

But this does not:

```
<<FeynCalc`
SetAttributes[MySymmetricFunction, Orderless]
Simplify[MySymmetricFunction[pResonance, pRho]*FV[NucleonOut, m] - MySymmetricFunction[pRho, pResonance]*FV[pNucleonOut, m]]
```

**edit2**
Thanks to @QuantomDot for pointing out my silly spelling mistake.

Comment: Could you give ``MySymmetricFunction`` the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless) attribute?

Comment: `Set[MySymmetricFunction, Orderless]` is a complete solution.

Comment: @evanb you mean `SetAttributes`.

Comment: `Orderless` has [interesting effects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26182/52) on pattern matching.

Comment: This does not work together with the FeynCalc package, so it seems.

Comment: Whoops, copy&pasta mistake

Comment: `NucleonOut` is not the same as `pNucleonOut`.

Comment: Thank's a lot. Been working non stop for hours. Gotta take a break now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SetAttributes[msf, Orderless]
msf[x, y] - msf[y, x]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but please see my follow up question