# Deleting quasi-duplicates from large list efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the need to remove "duplicates" from large (>10K members) lists, where a "duplicate" is either a verbatim duplication, *or* the element's second entry exists as a first entry for some "earlier" member in the list.

E.G., given

```
testcase = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {1, 3}, {6, 4}, {9, 4}, {7, 5}, {6, 7}, {5, 7}}
```

the desired result would be `{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {7, 5}}`.

Of course the trivial method is `DeleteDuplicates[testcase, #2[[2]] == #1[[1]] &]`, but this goes exponential, as hinted to in the MMA documentation.

I've been pondering for a bit, shooting blanks so far, looking for any ideas toward an *efficient* solution.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to select minimal subsets?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8154/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Off the top of my head I'd do this.  It should have good computational complexity (hash table) though as a general pattern-based method it is unlikely to be as fast a a numeric or compiled approach:

```
Module[{f},
 f[{x_, _}] := (f[{_, x}] = False; True);
 Select[testcase, f]
]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {7, 5}}
> ```

It does have the advantage of being easy to apply to a series of lists: just omit the `Module`.

I am assuming you have already filtered verbatim duplicates with `DeleteDuplicates[testcase]` beforehand.

---

The code above was written in haste, without considering optimizations.  After seeing belisarius's suggestion I propose this:

```
Module[{f, g},
  g[_] = True;
  f[{x_, _}] := (g[x] = False; True);
  Cases[testcase, {_, _?g}?f]
]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {7, 5}}
> ```

Timings:

```
big = DeleteDuplicates @ RandomInteger[999, {50000, 2}];

Module[{f},
  f[{x_, _}] := (f[{_, x}] = False; True);
  Select[big, f]
] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {3.681, 4001}
> ```

```
Module[{f, g},
  g[_] = True;
  f[{x_, _}] := (g[x] = False; True);
  Cases[big, {_, _?g}?f]
] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.031, 4001}
> ```

I expect that this can be improved further, but I'm out of time.  I'd start by trying `"DefinitionsReordering" -> "None"` as done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8160/121).

---

Two more variations that are not as fast, but I like the style (the first one is pretty close):

```
Module[{g}, Cases[testcase, {x_, Except[_?g]} /; (g[x] = True)]]

Module[{g}, DeleteCases[testcase, {_, _?g} | {x_ /; (g[x] = True;), _}]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {7, 5}}
>
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {7, 5}}
> ```

Comment: `Reap@Module[{f},
  f[{x_, _}] := (f[{_, x}] = False; True);
  Scan[If[f@#, Sow@#] &, testcase]]` is like 10% faster here, nevertheless I agree that the meat is in the pattern matching thing

Comment: That gave me an idea ... try the performance of `Reap@Module[{f},
  f[{x_, y_}] := (f[x] = False);
  Scan[If[f@#[[2]], , , f@Sow@#] &, testcase]]`

Comment: @belisarius: Clever, and surprisingly quick! I came up with a couple of ideas at dinner, will test and post back - I'd tried something similar to first comment & Mr. W's, your new one is much more efficient in the few tests I've just run.

Comment: @rasher Yup, the idea was eliminating the pattern matching

Comment: @belisarius: Please, make your comment an answer. My idea using a dummy array with prepend/delete/scan was only a bit faster, and is fugly-kludge-a-licious... your's (and Mr. W's) are pretty and fast. Using it now in an updated idea from another post. Thanks. both of you!

Comment: Ah, the master Wizard strikes again! Your latter one is faster yet. Color me impressed again.

Comment: @rasher Thanks.  Here's another variation: `Module[{g}, Cases[big, {x_, Except[_?g]} /; (g[x] = True)]]` -- not quite as fast but I like the style.

Comment: Accepted, fastest so far, and *belisautius* appears to have elected not to post his elegant version as an answer. Thanks again both!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not too different:

```
f[x_, y_] := (f[_, x] = Sequence[]; {x, y});
g[x_, y_] := (g[x, y] = Sequence[]; {x, y});
```

Test data:

```
testcase = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {1, 3}, {6, 
    4}, {9, 4}, {7, 5}, {6, 7}, {5, 7}};
```

Applying:

```
g@@@(f@@@ testcase)
```

yields:

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {7, 5}}
```

Note in this particular case replacing head with f would remove the repeated {1,3} because of the {3,4} earlier in the list. However, would not work in general, e.g. repeated elements (with distinct sub elements) next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate solution, that quite literally selects every element whose second entry does not exists as a first entry for some "earlier" member:

```
Module[{firstElems = testcase[[All, 1]], i = 0}, 
 Select[testcase, FreeQ[Take[firstElems, i++], #[[2]]] &]]
```