# How do I prune a list of pairs of numbers so that each number occurs on only one pair?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

How do I select only the first pair of numbers in which a number occurs from a list of pairs of numbers?

For example, I have

```
{{20, 11}, {17, 20}, {26, 5}, {14, 9}, {18, 13}, {19, 11}}
```

I would like to get

```
{{20, 11}, {26, 5}, {14, 9}, {18, 13}}
```

and If I have

```
{{20, 11}, {17, 20}, {26, 13}, {14, 26}, {11, 20}, {18, 13}, {19, 11}}
```

I would want

```
{{20, 11}, {26, 13}}
```

That is: the resulting list must have the properties that

- it contains only pairs from the original list, and that
- it has been pruned (just*) to the extent that each number occurs in only one pair.

*Ideally the result should retains the most pairs (realizing that my examples above may not accomplish this).

Comment: Your problem is under-specified.  A single number might appear in several pairs in such a way that there is no unique answer.  Please constrain your problem to avoid such ambiguity.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Goot point; but I'll accept any answer that has the two properties listed. Ideally, I'd like the one that produces retains the most pairs though (I'll add that to the question).

Comment: How large are the lists you intend to use this on? The current only answer is clean and suffices for small lists but will become horribly inefficient for large lists, but if your lists *are* small, it's probably as tight of an answer possible.

Comment: @rasher: Never more than 10.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Ah, then you're golden with Kguler`s very pretty answer. Interesting problem on large lists...

Comment: @rasher: A general answer would be good here to (others may need it to apply to longer lists).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Does order matter? That is, must results appear in same order as the original list?

Comment: @rasher: Short answer, yes: original list order should be preserved.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Added my first thought, will ponder further...

Comment: @rasher: Looks great!

Comment: Related: [(8154)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8154/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe

```
lst = {{20, 11}, {17, 20}, {26, 5}, {14, 9}, {18, 13}, {19, 11}};
DeleteDuplicates[lst, Intersection[##] != {} &]
(* {{20, 11}, {26, 5}, {14, 9}, {18, 13}} *)

lst2 = {{20, 11}, {17, 20}, {26, 13}, {14, 26}, {11, 20}, {18, 13}, {19, 11}};
DeleteDuplicates[lst2, Intersection[##] != {} &]
(* {{20, 11}, {26, 13}} *)
```

Comment: Looks good. Bear with me while I check it in production.

Comment: I'd venture on large lists this will get very slow... but neat and tidy,  +1

Comment: thank you @rasher. Re `slow`, thought about using `Message` to add " caveat emptor: ..." , but that  would have made it too long :)

Answer (score 13):

Update: I was able to improve the performance of `pruner2b` below with a couple of suggestions from the screw on my cell block. In honor of the booze we make in the toilets here, I'll call it `pruno`:

```
pruno[lst_] := Module[{f, g},
   g[_] = True;
   f[a_, b_] := If[g[a] && g[b], g[a] = g[b] = False; {a, b},Unevaluated@Sequence[]];
   f @@@ lst];
```

The original idea and updated benchmark follow.

Just a quick-and-dirty idea:

```
pruner2b[lst_] := Module[{f},
                f[_] = True;
                Map[If[f[#[[1]]] && f[#[[2]]], (f[#] = False)&/@#; #,Unevaluated@Sequence[]] &, lst]]
```

This returns precisely the same results as *Kguler*'s `DeleteDuplicates` solution (I've not proofed that this is "optimal", in the sense of maximizing length of result).

A quick performance comparison using `lstx = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, {10000, 2}];` to generate a test list and then incrementally increasing the amount used:
[image]

By 500 pairs `pruno` is over 2 orders of magnitude faster than using `DeleteDuplicates` and significantly leads `pruner2b`, ran out of patience much beyond that...

Taking further advantage of the speed of the pattern matcher, this is even faster for lists >~1K pairs on the loungebook (with a nod to Mr. W's "cool kids" comment - no performance difference using `##&[]`, but certainly prettier):

```
prunod[lst_] := Module[{f, g},
   g[_] = True;
   f[a_?g, b_?g] := (g[a] = g[b] = False; {a, b});
   f[_, _] = ## &[];
   f @@@ lst];
```

[image]

Comment: The opening is a bit terrifying, but +1 nevertheless...

Comment: By the way `Unevaluated @ Sequence[]` is so mundane; all the cool kids use `##&[]` now. ;^)  [(3705)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/121)

Answer (score 4):

A bit shorter than the answer by [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) is

```
list = {{20, 11}, {17, 20}, {26, 13}, {14, 26}, {11, 20}, {18, 13}, {19, 11}};
DeleteDuplicates[list, IntersectingQ]
```

But it also gets really slow for large lists.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to ciao's

```
list = {{20, 11}, {17, 20}, {26, 5}, {14, 9}, {18, 13}, {19, 11}};

Clear[f]

f[_] = True;

If[f[#1], f[#1] = False;
   If[f[#2], f[#2] = False;
    {##}, Nothing], Nothing] & @@@ list
```

> ```
> {{20, 11}, {26, 5}, {14, 9}, {18, 13}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The following works and is fast for big lists.

```
delDuPairs[list_] :=
 Module[{flist = Flatten@list},
  Delete[list, Transpose@
    {Union@Flatten@Ceiling[Rest /@ Select[
           GatherBy[Range@Length[flist], flist[[#]] &], 
           Length[#] > 1 &]/2]}
   ] ]
```

The function is based upon [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/4626) answer to a different question.  I'm sure it could be cleaned up a bit.

```
lstx = RandomInteger[{1, 100000}, {100000, 2}];

First@AbsoluteTiming[delDuPairs[lstx]]
```

> 0.397049