# How to delete that subset with succinct method?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a such list:

```
data={{4, 2}, {4, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}}
```

Because the `{4,2},{4,2,3},{4,5}` is subset of `{4, 2, 3, 5}`,so I want to delete they to get `{{4,2,3,5},{4,6}}`.There is mess method:

```
DeleteCases[data, _?(Or @@ 
     Function[list, SubsetQ[list, #]] /@ DeleteCases[data, #] &)]
```

> {{4,2,3,5},{4,6}}

But I think must have some concise method can do this,such as by `DeleteDuplicates`,`Union` and other something.But I have fail to implement that.

Comment: Related converse problem: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8154/121

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate.  Please review the "original" linked at the top of your post and let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well,I think this two posts have little difference still,maybe they are a good reference for each other.But I will would let the reader to decide they are duplicate or not. :)

Comment: Please consider editing this question to highlight the difference from the existing linked question.  That will automatically add this to the reopen review queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {{4, 2}, {4, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}};

DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[data, Length] // Reverse, 
 ContainsAll[#1, #2] &]

(*  {{4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}}  *)
```

Or as [`yode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21532/yode) pointed out, this can be simplified to

```
DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[data, Length] // Reverse, ContainsAll]

(*  {{4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}}  *)
```

Comment: +1)..It's seem we can omit the `[#1, #2] &` :)

Comment: Slightly simpler: `DeleteDuplicates[Reverse@Sort@data, ContainsAll]` (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
Pick[VertexList@#, VertexInDegree@#, 1] &@ RelationGraph[SubsetQ, data]
```

> {{4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}}

Or

```
GraphComputation`SourceVertexList @RelationGraph[And[UnsameQ@##,SubsetQ@##]&, data]
```

> {{4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}}

Comment: Upvote for `And[UnsameQ@##, SubsetQ@##] &`.I have to say I consider it for a long time to avoid produce multigraph but fail to do it. :)

Comment: How long have you know the package `GraphComputation` introduced?