# Deleting list elements by comparing to another list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have two lists as follow. The first is

```
p={{"j","d","x"},{"d","k","z"}}
```

and the second one is:

```
l={{"a","b","c"},{"a","x"},{"g","f","k"},{"d","a","k","o","l","z"},
  {"j","a","d","o","x"}}
```

I want to delete those combination that exist in `p` from `l`, such that I get:

```
{{"a","b","c"},{"a","x"},{"g","f","k"}}
```

this is because `{"d","a","k","o","l","z"}` contains `{"d","k","z"}` and  `{"j","a","d","o","x"}` contains `{"j","d","x"}`. 
The way I did this so far is:

```
DeleteCases[l,_?(ContainsAll[{"j","d","x"}])]
DeleteCases[%,_?(ContainsAll[{"d","k","z"}])]
```

The above does the job, yet for a long list of `p` this would be ineffective as one would have to use 100s of DeleteCases commands. I wonder if there is a clever way of doing this?

**EDIT:**
As @rhermans suggested I am going to give a realistic example, let us make a list of all English words, separated by their letters as follow:

```
En = Alphabet["English"];
Characters[ToLowerCase[WordList[Language -> "English"]]];
Select[%, SubsetQ[En, ToLowerCase[#1]] &];
EN = Map[Sort, Map[DeleteDuplicates, %]];
```

We then make a list containing all the subsets of size 3 from the English alphabet, that is

```
l = Subsets[En, {3}]
```

Now for `l[[1 ;; 1000]]` delete the cases in EN that contain `l`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher This is not a suitable command, I tried it.

Comment: There are many solutions, can you provide a sample of a realistic big data set to compare performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[l, _?(Function[x,Or@@(ContainsAll[x,#]&/@p)])]
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "x"}, {"g", "f", "k"}}

or

```
DeleteCases[l, _?(Or@@(Function[t,ContainsAll[#,t]]/@p)&)]
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "x"}, {"g", "f", "k"}}

**Update:** A variant of Mr. Wizard's `filter` using `OrderlessPatternSequence`:

```
ClearAll[filter3]
filter3[l_, p_] := Module[{f}, f[{Alternatives @@ 
  (OrderlessPatternSequence[##& @@ #,___]& /@ p)}] := 0; f[_] := 1; Pick[l, f /@ l, 1]]  

filter3[l, p]
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "x"}, {"g", "f", "k"}}

This is faster than both `filter` and `filter2`:

```
filter3[EN, ss~Take~1000] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {9.43515, 19155}

versus

```
filter[EN, ss~Take~1000] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {13.1298, 19155}

```
filter2[EN, ss~Take~1000] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {13.1131, 19155}

Comment: Nice update. I always seem to use `Orderless` over `OrderlessPatternSequence` -- habits are hard to change I guess.

Answer (score 6):

```
Pick[l, Or @@@ Outer[SubsetQ, l, p, 1], False]
```

or

```
Fold[DeleteCases[#1, _?(ContainsAll[#2])] &, l, p]
```

or

```
Fold[{a, b} \[Function] Select[a, ! SubsetQ[#, b] &], l, p]
```

or (parallelized and thus should be faster than the others for longer lists)

```
Pick[
 l,
 ParallelTable[Or @@ Map[SubsetQ[x, #] &, p], {x, l}, 
  Method -> "CoarsestGrained"],
 False
 ]
```

Answer (score 6):

This question is related to: [How to select minimal subsets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8154/121)

If you want a solution that performs well with a long $p$ list you do *not* want one that rescans naively for each of its elements, as supplied in the other answers. (Sorry, guys.)

Instead try:

```
filter[l_, p_] :=
  Module[{f},
    SetAttributes[f, Orderless];
    (f[##, ___] = Sequence[]) & @@@ p;
    f[else__] := {else};
    f @@@ l
  ]

filter2[l_, p_] :=
  Module[{f, g},
    SetAttributes[f, Orderless];
    (f[##, ___] = True) & @@@ p;
    g[a_] /; f @@ a = Sequence[];
    g[a_] := a;
    g /@ l
  ]

filter[l, p]
filter2[l, p]
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "x"}, {"f", "g", "k"}}
>
> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "x"}, {"g", "f", "k"}}    (* original set order *)
> ```

These will actually finish on your sample problem, whereas the others will run indefinitely:

```
En = Alphabet["English"];
Characters[ToLowerCase[DictionaryLookup[{"English", "*"}]]];
Select[%, SubsetQ[En, ToLowerCase[#1]] &];
EN = Map[Sort, Map[DeleteDuplicates, %]];
ss = Subsets[En, {3}];

filter[EN, ss ~Take~ 1000]  // Length // AbsoluteTiming

filter2[EN, ss ~Take~ 1000] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {9.09321, 19155}
>
> {9.09125, 19155}
> ```

---

### String Patterns

The method above was written to be general, but if your sample problem truly is representative you may consider String patterns as an alternative:

```
pat = StringRiffle[#, {"*", "*", "*"}] & /@ Take[ss, 1000];

joinEN = StringJoin /@ EN;

Pick[joinEN, StringMatchQ[joinEN, pat], False] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {5.16058, 19155}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to use bit vectors. Here I convert the subsets and words into bit vectors:

```
toBits[list:{__}] := Total[
    list /. Thread[CharacterRange["a","z"] -> 2^Range[0,25]],
    If[StringQ @ list[[1]], {1}, {2}]
]

bWords = toBits[EN]; //RepeatedTiming
bSets = toBits[ss]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.71, Null}
>
> {0.013, Null}

Now, for the Boolean contains/free predicate, we want to check whether the word is missing a letter (bit) from the set. I will define the following predicate:

```
bAndQ[a_, b_] := Unitize @ BitAnd[a, b]
```

We can use the predicate for set membership. For example:

```
bAndQ[BitNot[Range[20]], 6]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Note how 6, 7, 14 and 15 (which all have bits 2^1 and 2^2 set) return 0, the others return 1. For speed reasons, it will be convenient to define the not version of `bWords`:

```
nbWords = BitNot[bWords]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00027, Null}

Putting things together:

```
r = Total @ Table[bAndQ[nbWords, b], {b, bSets[[;;1000]]}]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.46, Null}

The dimensions of `r` are:

```
Dimensions[r]
```

> {91926}

Each element of `r` is equal to 1000 if it does not contain any of the sets. So, the number of words that don't contain any of the sets is:

```
Count[r, 1000]
```

> 19155

in agreement with the other answers. If you want to know which words these are, you can use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick):

```
Pick[EN, r, 1000] //Short
```

> {{a},{a,h},<<19151>>,{e,g,o,s,t,y,z},{g,m,r,u,y,z}}

Answer (score 3):

```
p = 
  {{"j", "d", "x"}, {"d", "k", "z"}};

list = 
  {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "x"}, {"g", "f", "k"}, {"d", "a", "k", "o", "l", "z"}, {"j", "a", "d", "o", "x"}};
```

Define a deconstructing function

```
f[a_][b_] /; Or @@ Map[ContainsAll[b, #] &, a] := Nothing

f[_][b_] := b
```

and map it

```
f[p] /@ list
```

{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "x"}, {"g", "f", "k"}}