# Delete the sublist which can be others' subsets

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, filtering, subset

given

```
lst = {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}}
```

I want to remove all the sublists which is any other's subset. For the above example, remove `{6, 8}`

I wrote this

```
lst //. {x___List, a_List, c___List, b_List, y___List} /; (SubsetQ[a, b] 
|| SubsetQ[b, a]) :> {x, If[SubsetQ[b, a], b, a], c, y}
```

But it's kind of slow.

---

The following method comes from a qq group

```
Intersection[lst, 
    Flatten[Select[
            GatherBy[
                Flatten[(y \[Function] Subsets[y, {Min[Length /@ #], Length[y]}]) /@ # &[
                        DeleteDuplicates[lst]], 1], Sort], Length[#] == 1 &], 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
multiSubsetQ = Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, ##] == {} &;

lst = {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}};
```

We can use  `multiSubsetQ` with `Select` as in Roman's answer or with [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) and get sink vertices:

```
rg = SimpleGraph @ RelationGraph[multiSubsetQ, Select[lst, Count[lst, #] == 1 &]];

Graph[rg, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
GeneralUtilities`GraphSinks @ rg
```

> ```
> {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8, 9}}
> ```

```
GraphComputation`SinkVertexList @ rg
```

> ```
> {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8, 9}}
> ```

Alternatively, we can use the ResourceFunction [MultisetComplement](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultisetComplement) to define `multiSubsetQ`:

```
multiSubsetQ2 = ResourceFunction["MultisetComplement"][##] == {} &;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}};

Select[lst, Count[lst, x_ /; SubsetQ[x, #]] == 1 &]
(*    {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8, 9}}    *)
```

### Update

As @hadesth has pointed out, we need to first define a subset function that takes the multiplicity of elements into account:

```
mysubsetQ[A_List, B_List] := 
  Length[B] <= Length[A] && Sort[A][[;; Length[B]]] == Sort[B]
```

(or use @kglr's `multiSubsetQ` or `multiSubsetQ2` function).

Now it works more generally:

```
lst = {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}, {1, 1}};

Select[lst, Count[lst, x_ /; mysubsetQ[x, #]] == 1 &]
(*    {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8, 9}, {1, 1}}    *)
```

Comment: it has some problem, as SubsetQ[{1, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 1}] will return True

Comment: Ah yes, as the documentation states: "[`SubsetQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetQ.html) does not account for multiplicity of elements." Thanks @hadesth

Comment: you also need to remove duplicates from the input list.

Comment: @kglr why? If `lst = {{1}, {1}, {2}}` then according to the description the result should be `{{2}}`, not `{{1}, {2}}`. "[...] remove all the sublists which is any other's subset"

Comment: Roman, good point ... of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}};

Intersection[list,Flatten[Select[GatherBy[Flatten[(y\[Function]Subsets[y,{Min[Length/@#],Length[y]}])/@#&[DeleteDuplicates[list]],1],Sort],Length[#]==1&],1]]
```

(* {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8, 9}} *)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your set elements are all positive integers, you could convert the sets to a tally form, and then use `` Internal`ListMin `` to prune sets. (I gave a variation of this approach in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152957/45431), but in that question minimal subsets were desired instead of maximal subsets). Here is an example using this idea:

```
lst = {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}};

i = Total[
    Replace[lst, s_ :> UnitVector[9, s], {2}],
    {2}
]
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
> 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}}

Then:

```
r = -Internal`ListMin[-i]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
> 0, 0, 0}}

Converting back to sets:

```
Pick[Range[9], #, 1]& /@ r
```

> {{6, 8, 9}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}}

To package this up as a function (and support multisets), I will introduce two helper functions:

```
fromSets[sets_] := With[{m = Max[sets]},
    Total[
        Replace[sets, s_ :> UnitVector[m, s], {2}],
        {2}
    ]
]

toSets[lists_] := (Flatten @ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2[[1]], #1]&, #]&) /@ lists
```

For example:

```
fromSets[{{2,4}, {1,2,2,4}, {1,1,3}}]
toSets[%]
```

> {{0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1, 0}}

> {{2, 4}, {1, 2, 2, 4}, {1, 1, 3}}

Then, a function that selects maximal sets would be:

```
maximal[sets_] := toSets @ -Internal`ListMin[-fromSets @ sets]
```

Your example:

```
maximal[{{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}}]
```

> {{6, 8, 9}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}}

@Roman's example with a multiset:

```
maximal[{{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}, {1, 1}}]
```

> {{6, 8, 9}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {1, 1}}

Using `` Internal`ListMin `` should be orders of magnitude faster than the other answers for large lists of sets.

Comment: (1) It is not hard to extend to arbitrary elements using `Union` to get the universe set, and perhaps a `Dispatch` table to associate elements to unit vectors. (2) `Internal\`ListMin` now is in the Wolfram Function Repository as `ResourceFunction["ParetoListMinima"]`. So one need no longer rely on an `Internal` context function (some people are put off by such).

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8}, {6, 8, 9}, {1, 1}};
```

Another way using `SequencePosition` and `Pick`:

```
p = Partition[lst, 2, 1, 1];

test = Length@SequencePosition[#1, #2] == 0 & @@ ReverseSortBy[#, Length] &;

Pick[lst, test /@ p]

(*{{1, 5}, {2, 5}, {6, 8, 9}, {1, 1}}*)
```