# Orderless pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, variable-definitions, attributes

The MMA docs state that "In matching patterns with Orderless functions, all possible orders of arguments are tried".

Why then does the following not work?

```
plus[x__Integer, y__Real] := x+y
Attributes[plus] = {Orderless}
plus[2.5, 3]
```

Got:

```
plus[2.5, 3]
```

Expected:

```
5.5
```

Note that the expression does match the pattern.

```
MatchQ[plus[2.5, 3], plus[x__Integer, y__Real]]
```

returns `True` if and only if `plus` has the `Orderless` Attribute.

Comment: Related: [(304)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/304/121), [(5067)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5067/121), [(18060)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18060/121)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the documentation needs to be more clear on this; the order of definitions *is important:*

```
Remove[plus]

Attributes[plus] = {Orderless};
plus[x__Integer, y__Real] := x + y

plus[2.5, 3]
```

> ```
> 5.5
> ```

So the `Orderless` attribute must be active at the time the definition is created.

Noteworthy is that definitions made before setting the attribute can cohabit with those made after setting it in a very useful way.  For years I didn't know this until Simon Woods made me aware of it with this answer:

- [How to Derive Tuples Without Replacement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/how-to-derive-tuples-without-replacement/7979#7979)

Here is my own application of that behavior:

- [How to select minimal subsets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8160/121)

---

### OrderlessPatternSequence

Version 10.1 introduces [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html) which allows orderless behavior to be applied one definition (or even pattern) at a time.

```
Remove[plus]

plus[OrderlessPatternSequence[x__Integer, y__Real]] := x + y

plus[a_, b_] /; a < b := {a, b}
```

The first definition works in orderless fashion:

```
plus[2.5, 3, 1.8]
```

> ```
> 7.3
> ```

The second definition retains normal behavior:

```
plus[3, 1]
```

> ```
> plus[3, 1]
> ```