# Tuples of elements from list excluding anything with repeated values

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, tuples

What I would like to do is the following.

For a given list of elements; say (0,1,2,3,4) I would like to obtain all possible combinations of five, but not the ones with ANY repeated values. That is I don't want to see anything with two elements equal like (0,0,1,2,3), (0,1,2,3,0), etc etc.

Tuples gives all possible combinations back

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
Tuples[list, 5]
```

I found this answer [Tuples Without Replacements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/how-to-derive-tuples-without-replacement)

But this is not I want to do.

I also tried to use Subsets and Reverse

```
Subsets[list, {5}]
Reverse /@ Subsets[list, {5}]
```

But the result of the above is to give only the $(0,1,2,3,4)$ and $(4,3,2,1,0)$.

I checked a couple of other replies here and I have not been able to find anything relevant to get me started.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try Select[Tuples[list, 5],Length@Union@#==5&]

Comment: or Permutations@list

Comment: Great reply. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe this question is a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = {a, b, s, t}

tlst = Tuples[lst, 3]

srtlst = Cases[tlst, Except[ {___, x_, ___, x_, ___}]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use [`Permutations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations):

```
Permutations[lst]
```

> {{a, b, s, t}, {a, b, t, s}, {a, s, b, t}, {a, s, t, b}, {a, t, b, s}, {a, t, 
>     s, b}, {b, a, s, t}, {b, a, t, s}, {b, s, a, t}, {b, s, t, a}, {b, t, a, 
>     s}, {b, t, s, a}, {s, a, b, t}, {s, a, t, b}, {s, b, a, t}, {s, b, t, 
>     a}, {s, t, a, b}, {s, t, b, a}, {t, a, b, s}, {t, a, s, b}, {t, b, a, 
>     s}, {t, b, s, a}, {t, s, a, b}, {t, s, b, a}}

If you want to restrict to 3-element sublists as in @Anxon's answer use the second argument of [`Permutations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations):

```
Permutations[lst], {3}]
```

> {{a, b, s}, {a, b, t}, {a, s, b}, {a, s, t}, {a, t, b}, {a, t, s}, {b, a, 
>     s}, {b, a, t}, {b, s, a}, {b, s, t}, {b, t, a}, {b, t, s}, {s, a, b}, {s, a,
>      t}, {s, b, a}, {s, b, t}, {s, t, a}, {s, t, b}, {t, a, b}, {t, a, s}, {t, 
>     b, a}, {t, b, s}, {t, s, a}, {t, s, b}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Tuples[{a, b, s, t}, 3];
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3) with `OrderlessPatternSequence`

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[list, {{OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, a_, _]}}]
```

{{a, b, s}, {a, b, t}, {a, s, b}, {a, s, t}, {a, t, b}, {a, t, s}, {b,
a, s}, {b, a, t}, {b, s, a}, {b, s, t}, {b, t, a}, {b, t, s}, {s,
a, b}, {s, a, t}, {s, b, a}, {s, b, t}, {s, t, a}, {s, t, b}, {t, a,
b}, {t, a, s}, {t, b, a}, {t, b, s}, {t, s, a}, {t, s, b}}

Using `DeleteCases` with `OrderlessPatternSequence`

```
DeleteCases[{OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, a_, _]}] @ list
```

(* same result *)

**Timings** with `Tuples[Range[20], 3]` (8000 elements)

`Permutations` (Carl Woll): 0.00015 sec

`Cases` (Anxon Pués): 0.011 sec

`DeleteCases` (Eldo): 0.016 sec

`SequenceSplit` (Eldo): 1.019 sec

Comment: It's nice to see these newer functions get advertised on MSE. But bear in mind that some usages might be unreasonably slow. And for this problem, the method shown by @CarlWoll is The Way To Do It.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, I included the timings. Especially  `SequenceSplit` gets horribly slow with longer lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Tuples[{a, b, s, t}, 3];
```

Using `Select` and `CountDistinct`:

```
Select[list, CountDistinct[#] == 3 &]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, s}, {a, b, t}, {a, s, b}, {a, s, t}, {a, t, b}, {a, t, s}, 
>  {b, a, s}, {b, a, t}, {b, s, a}, {b, s, t}, {b, t, a}, {b, t, s},
>  {s, a, b}, {s, a, t}, {s, b, a}, {s, b, t}, {s, t, a}, {s, t, b}, 
>  {t, a,b}, {t, a, s}, {t, b, a}, {t, b, s}, {t, s, a}, {t, s, b}}
> ```