# Convert String to Integer from a huge string database in a very fast way?

Tags: performance-tuning, import, string-manipulation, conversion

I have a huge string database with the form such as {{position},{1,2,3,4,5,..}}, and I want to convert such database to Interger data in a very quick way.

In the following example, I created a string database (instead of my real simulation database).

```
StringData = {};
steps=5000; (* for testing, in real simulation it is large*)
Do[AppendTo[StringData, {"Position"<>ToString[ii],"0,1,1,1,22,1,2,14,5,2,2,1,5,"}], {ii, 1, steps}];

strtolist = ConstantArray[{}, Length[StringData]];
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[StringData], ii++,
   strtolist[[ii]] = ToExpression[StringSplit[StringData[[ii]][[2]], ","]];
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming

strtolist = ConstantArray[{}, Length[StringData]];
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[StringData], ii++,
   strtolist[[ii]] = IntegerPart/@Internal`StringToDouble/@StringSplit[StringData[[ii]][[2]], ","];
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.248431, Null}
>
> {0.100303, Null}

The second way is much fast. My real simulation is a large database and I wonder **whether there are even quicker way to do such converting?** for example without doing the outside for-loop? Thank you very much!

> **one additional problem using `` Internal`StringToDouble ``:**
>
> when the number is very large as the following example

```
test = {"0", "33837677493872221", "311462297063636041906"};
numstr1 = IntegerPart /@ Internal`StringToDouble /@ test
numstr2 = IntegerPart /@ Internal`StringToDouble /@ test[[3]]
```

the results:

> {0, 33837677493872220, IntegerPart[$Failed["Bignum"]]}
>
> 311462297063636041906

Why numstr2 works good while numstr1 doesn't work? It seems `` Internal`StringToDouble `` works fine with single string not string lists?

> **What if the StringData contains number like "-1","-2" and so on? Only thinking about Integer number (including negative and positive). Is there**
>   **any other way to do the same work instead of using `ToExpression`?**

Comment: try `Map[FromDigits, StringSplit[StringData[[All, 2]], ","], {-1}]`?

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test your method. In addition I add one small question in the end. Seems ``Internal`StringToDouble`` does not work with with a lists containing large number but fine with one single string. Do you know why?@kglr

Comment: `Map[FromDigits, StringSplit[StringData[[All, 2]], ","], {-1}]` works good. Is it possible works with  string list with negitave number such as "-1" and so on? @kglr

Comment: because ``Internal`StringToDouble`` does not have the `Listable` attribute. You can make listable version using ``istd = Internal`StringToDouble;
SetAttributes[istd, Listable]``

Comment: @kglr that's an interesting subtlety to `Listable`... I hadn't realized it would take precedence over evaluating to ``Internal`StringToDouble``. I assumed the `Head` would evaluate, then any `Attributes` would apply but I suppose it's the other way around?

Comment: @b3m2a1, hadn't thought about it. Now that you mention it, I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7979/125) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71464/125) re order of definitions and setting attributes.

Comment: `numstr2` is still a string because you mapped on a string not a list.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen, yes you are right. I didn't realize that.Thank you for pointing out. That's very interesting.

Comment: @kglr, when I make the Listable  as you suggested `SetAttributes[istd, Listable]`, the problems still exists.

Comment: @XuemeiGu, I misspoke; we need to define `istd` as:``istd[x_]:= Internal`StringToDouble[x]; SetAttributes[istd, Listable];`` and use it as `IntegerPart @ istd @  StringSplit[StringData[[All, 2]], ","]` ( but this is slower than mapping ``Internal`StringToDouble`` at level `{-1}` and using `IntegerPart` on the entire list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
strtolist2 = Map[FromDigits, StringSplit[StringData[[All, 2]], ","], {-1}]

strtolist3 = IntegerPart @ Map[Internal`StringToDouble, 
   StringSplit[StringData[[All, 2]], ","], {-1}];

strtolist3  == strtolist2 == strtolist
```

> True

Both are about twice as fast as `For` loop with `` IntegerPart/@Internal`StringToDouble/@... ``

Comment: Yes, it is fast but one problem is it cannot work with negative number such as “-1” because of FromDigits. Is there any chance also working with negative number string?@kglr

Comment: @XuemeiGu, please see the update. The second alternative can handle signed numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using `istd[x_] := Internal`StringToDouble[x];` `SetAttributes[istd, Listable];strtolist6 = IntegerPart@istd@StringSplit[StringData[[All, 2]], ","]; ` cannot solve large number strings such as `str={{"Position1", "0,1,201111111111111111,1,-1"}, {"Position2",  "0,1,201111111111111111,1,-1"}}`.

Answer (score 6):

`ToExpression` is very fast for correct Mathematica syntax input. So the key idea is to create an input string for `ToExpression` that delivers the expected result for the huge string database in one go:

```
StringData // 
   Extract[{All, 2}] // 
   StringRiffle[#, {"{{", "Nothing},{", "Nothing}}"}] & // 
   ToExpression
```

The odd looking `"Nothing}"` in `StringRiffle` is required to make the parser ignore the terminating comma (i.e., `"0,1,1,1,22,1,2,14,5,2,2,1,5,"`) in each input string.

`ToExpression` also handles negative and very large numbers correctly.

Comment: Of course, one should always be careful with `ToExpression[]`.